# Nested Dialog fragments getActivity().findViewById return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, datepicker

I am using this class to show a date picker. It works as follow

- Receive the text view id then adds the selected date and time to this text view.

When I call it from fragments it works fine. But when I call it from another dialog fragment it shows the date picker then throws null pointer exception on setting the date in the text field.
While the dialog fragment is still inflated in the background and visible.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    TextView dateTextView;
    Date tempDate;
    Boolean isCurrentDate;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(int dateTextViewId, Boolean isCurrentDate) {
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("textField", dateTextViewId);
        bundle.putBoolean("flag", isCurrentDate);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setDateTextView(TextView dateTextView) {
        this.dateTextView = dateTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.dateTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(getArguments().getInt("textField"));
            isCurrentDate = getArguments().getBoolean("flag");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (isCurrentDate == false) {
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 18;
        }
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
        if (isCurrentDate)
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        else
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return dialog;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    DatePickerFragment.this.dateTextView.setText(view.getDayOfMonth() + "/" + (view.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + view.getYear());
                }
            };

}
```

This is how I inflate the dialog fragment

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_transaction_filter_item_list, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
```

And this is how I call the date picker fragment

```
val calenderFragment =
                DatePickerFragment.newInstance(binding.fromDateTextView.id, false)
            calenderFragment.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!, "")
```

The error message

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I am not sure why the id is not visible to the activity.

Comment: How is its working fine for fragment? you are calling `getActivity().findViewById` for this the view has to be part of `Activity` not `Fragment` . Its not a good idea to pass the view or view ID to `DialogFragment` . A better way to do it to create a Interface and pass the callback to calling component with selected date .

Comment: or you can create public class in your activity and call this from your child fragment

Comment: @ADM I think it is working fine with fragments because  I have a single activity and all fragments are attached to it.

Comment: Why do you have a public setter `setDateTextView` ? While you are also calling `findViewById` ? Its better to use an interface as i said above in comment .